# Using Regex to get text only between specified characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use negative and positive lookaheads to capture a certain area of text but am struggling. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.

This is the exact text I am using regex for: `Gold Coast area Partly cloudy.`

I got it from web-scraping, and the "`Partly cloudy`" text changes every day, so I can't use regex to search for those exact words.

I want to retrieve the words "Party cloudy" between "`Gold Coast area`" and the full stop after "`Partly cloudy`".

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What did you get from web-scraping exactly ? What have you tried so far as far as regex goes ?

Comment: Please read the condition of this site and show what you have got up to now. This site is about problem solution not about doing the work for you.

Comment: If you’re using BeautifulSoup for web-scraping, I’m pretty sure you can use it to find and get specific parts of a website. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Totally agree, please show what you already have and what's the issue. However - is that really a regex problem? You know that your string starts with 15 letters ("Gold Coast area") and ends with 1 ("."). So your searched substring is s[15:-1].strip(), right?

Comment: Try `r'Gold Coast area(.*)\.'`

Comment: Are you scraping a weather site? While it doesn’t solve the regex question, many weather sites offer an API in json format. It would be a lot easier and you wouldn’t have to account for multiple instances of “Gold Coast area” or words in between like “is” or “will be” causing unexpected issues with your regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a string always begins with `Gold Coast area` and ends with a full stop, you can just truncate the string without regex:

```
s = 'Gold Coast area Partly cloudy.'
new_s = s[16:-1]
print(new_s) # prints 'Partly cloudy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/([A-Za-z ]+?) area ([A-Za-z ]+)\./
```

It captures the area in the first capture group and the weather to the second one. In case you are only interested in the Gold Coast area then replace the first capture group with the hard-coded "Gold Coast" string.

As a proof of concept:

```
import re

arr = ["Gold Coast area Partly cloudy.", "Gold Coast area clear skies.", "Some other area overcast."]
for s in arr:
    match = re.match(r"([A-Za-z ]+?) area ([A-Za-z ]+)\.", s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1)+": "+match.group(2))
```

Outputs:

```
Gold Coast: Partly cloudy
Gold Coast: clear skies
Some other: overcast
```